# how to dismiss a progress dialog box when navigating from one activity to another using back and forth button?

Tags: android, dialog, back

I have 4 Activities in my android app. 1st leads to 2nd , 2nd to 3rd and so on.Each activity fetch some data from net.It takes some time in it so i have added a progress dialog box to let users know about it. Now the problem is that when i press the back button the progress dialog is still there. Where should i  write the dismiss() function to dismiss that progress dialog box?

PS:It dismisses when i press back button twice. Should i write dismiss on onStart(), onResume() or where ???

Here is the code :

```
private void onFileClick(Option option) {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setProgress(10);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
    progressDialog.show();
    Intent i;
        i = new Intent(this, ChannelVideoListActivity.class);   
        startActivity(i);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following.

```
onBackPressed(){
   progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: its by default that if a progress bar is visible and is not set cancellable(false); it will be dissmissed by default back button.
So this will make no change.

Answer (score 0):

//use Async Task for that.
call this line

```
new SomeTask(0).execute();


/** Inner class for implementing progress bar before fetching data **/

 private class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> 
    {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivityClass.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

        Dialog.setMessage("downloading...");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        //Task for doing something 

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {

        if(result==0)
        {
//do some thing
Intent i = new Intent(this, ChannelVideoListActivity.class);   
        startActivity(i);

        }

// after completed finished the progressbar
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: its not the problem of using AsyncTask.
he is just confused in how to properly use (when to show and dismiss progress bar)

Comment: @akkilis he is fetching some data from net so the way he implemented the progressdialog is not good approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You write your  `ChannelVideoListActivity` differently.

You might be calling function or writing code to load data from web and then show that or doing some data fetching operation.

Remove all from `onCreate()`  and put it in an `AsyncTask` 's `doInBackGround()` function and in AsyncTask's onPreExecute call your progress dialog and in `onPostExecute()` dismiss dialog.

Call this AsyncTask from onCreate() of  ChannelVideoListActivity after setContentView() method call as `new TaskClass().execute()`

and Simply call  ChannelVideoListActivity from it's previous with intent.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem in your flow of calling and dismiss of progress bar.

It should be:

- app started
- Activity 2 launched
- If there is network call, show progress bar
- wanna dismiss the progress bar and finish the activity

Or, as code:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**PS:** DONT start the progress bar before launching the new activity. Launch the activity and then start Progress bar.